# c# datagridview interactive filtering

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to make interactive filter for datagridview

I'm using EF to fetch data

```
           var query = from client in db.Clients
                        select new
                        {
                            client.Id,
                            client.Code,
                            client.Title
                        };

            clientsBs.DataSource = query.ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = clientsBs;
```

what's the best way to filter datagridview without another database query?
I tried this way, but it gives me no result/error...

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "Code like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: You may want to download Telerik UI for WinForms, their `DataGridView` provides this functionality automatically...

Comment: I don't want to use other components

Comment: It was just a suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Please indicate the errors if any. I think before setting the `DataSource` you should set it to `null`:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

**UPDATE:**

for Filtering the `DataGridView` you should change the DataSource and then bind it again:

```
var dataview = yourDataSet.Tables[tableIndex].DefaultView;
dataview.RowFilter = "Code like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
var newDT = dataview.ToTable();
var newDS = new DataSet();    
newDS.Tables.Add(newDT);
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = newDS;
```

Comment: Now it populates datagridview but not filtered

Comment: use `dataGridView1.RowFilter` instead of `bs.Filter`

Comment: RowFilter can't be used with dataGridView !

Comment: (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Code Like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

Comment: Now i get exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.